# C++ Pointers Tricky Summation Check

Tags: c++, list, pointers, sum

This is my first post, but I've frequented SO for help plenty of times. Still, please bear with me if I am not following proper etiquette. So to be brief, I'm working on a tricky problem involving pointers. I'll copy and paste it here because I'm worried I'd otherwise leave out important info:

Given a PHB list (1000 elements--ints from 1-100) of in_len (the pointer towards the last element) elements without any duplicates and pointed by in_list, the function will:

- (1) determine if it is possible to generate the sum of 31 within 5 consecutive elements;
- (2) if it is possible, return one list pointed by out_list that consists of positions of the list whose associated values add up to the number 31;
- (3) if it is possible, return the list length pointed by out_len.

Note that each element can only be used once. In addition, you need to return only one list if multiple cases exist. For example, if a PHB list is `{9, 5, 16, 22, 1, 37, 26, 14}`, then the returning value of the function is true, and out_list contains `{9, 5, 16, 1}` and its length is 4, or it contains `{9, 22}` and its length is 2. Note that the list `{16, 1, 14}` is not qualified since the set of three values spans more than 5 elements. As another example, if a PHB list is `{9, 5, 34}`, it returns false. out_list will be empty with a length of 0.

That's it. At first, I attempted hard coding in tons of options (along the lines of

```
if *in_list, *(in_list + 1), *(in_list + 2), *(in_list + 3), *(in_list+4)   
     add up to 31, 
//not actual code-just odd formatting

or *in_list, *(in_list + 1), *(in_list + 2), *(in_list + 3),  add up to 31
or *in_list, *(in_list + 1), *(in_list + 2), *(in_list + 4), add up to 31
or *in_list, *(in_list + 1), *(in_list + 3), *in_list + 4), add to 31
or *in_list, *(in_list + 2), *(in_list + 3), *(in_list + 4) add to 31
or *in_list, *(in_list + 1), *(in_list + 2),  add up to 31
```

etcetc, 
but quickly realized I just don't know what I'm doing here. Fortunately, the out_list only needs one list that adds up to 31. I'd appreciate any sort of help.
Thanks for your time!

The Solution (thank you all for your advice): 
http://pastebin.com/2sSShWty

Comment: The hard way involves a backtracking to check all the combinations of sublists to see if they meet your criteria. I think this can be solved with dynamic programming though

Comment: and by the way, don't try to impress the girls, just write `in_list[i]`, not `*(in_list + i)`

Comment: Ah that works much better @bolov. I just started working on creating a temp dynamically allocated array that could hold sets of 5, but haven't gotten far enough to get any conclusive results. Thanks for the tip

Comment: PHB is a list of 1000 ints ranging from 1-100 @Neil Kirk.

Comment: `in_len` is always 1000?

Comment: Oh gosh, how do I address you guys as opposed to myself? I typed (at)bolov and (at)Neil Kirk, but both defaulted to (at)Anthony

Comment: in_len is not always 1000. That was my misprint. const int PHB_LIST_LENGTH = 1000; is the max length

Comment: @Anthony take care: dynamically allocated arrays and dynamic programming refer to 2 completely different things

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I think what's best for me right now is just hitting the books some more and then taking another crack at it. Thank you for your advice

Comment: "PHB list (1000 elements--ints from 1-100)  elements without any duplicates". How can you have a list of 1000 ints from 1 to 100 with no duplicates?

Comment: I'm guessing the "with no duplicates" is an error - it doesn't affect the solution at all. (I should have added this to my previous comment but the 5 minute edit window expired.)

Comment: Hey all, here is the eventual solution: